# Suspend all firebase connections when react-native app is in background

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I want to suspend all firebase connections when my app goes in background. My app plays music in the background. I also create some realtime-database event handlers when the app is started. After the app is put in background and the app is playing music, I see that there is a continuous network activity in my app due to which the battery drains quickly. I checked out the below two methods

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Database#goOffline

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Database#goOnline

which seem to suggest that they would suspend and resume firebase connections respectively. I hooked up these methods with my app but I still see network activity in the app when the app is in background. So, I want to know are the above two methods suppose to suspend and resume all firebase connections? If not, then is there a way to achieve it?

I am checking the network activity in the "Energy Report" on Xcode. I have pasted a screenshot of the report below. Please observe that the app is shown to be in the background by grey blocks but there is also some amount of network activity.

[image]

Comment: What *exactly* are you observing?  What you're saying is kind of vague.  iOS app don't really have to capability of "continuous network activity" when in the background.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle

Comment: @DougStevenson I have added more information to the question. The app could be running in the background if the app is playing music. I am observing network activity in the "Energy Report" in Xcode. You can observe in the attached screenshot that the app is in background but there is some amount of network activity. The only network service that I use in the app is Firebase. So, I was thinking probably realtime database connections are creating the network activity.

Comment: How were you able to link what you've seen with Firebase?  Do you have some conclusive evidence?  Right now, it could be anything.  Do you have a minimal app that does nothing but set up a Firebase listener and go to the background?

Comment: That is why I wanted to know if there is a way to suspend all firebase connections. If there is, then I will suspend all connections when app goes in background and check network activity. On a side note, my complete server side infrastructure is set up using Firebase (Mix of realtime database, firebase functions and firebase queue workers). The mobile app doesn't connect to any other network service.

Comment: goOffline should eliminate all networking in the SDK.  But you're saying that doesn't work.  I'm saying perhaps it *does* work, but you have something else going on in your app that's actually causing the traffic.  The only way to prove that it's the fault of the Firebase SDK's fault is to eliminate everything except that, and watch it behave badly.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I will try to add find some more conclusive evidence and report back.